# Angular two (restrict: 'A') directives with same options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use two directives on same element

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div my-draggable my-resizable options="myOptions">test</div>
</div>
```

and I am getting error in the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=myDraggable&p1=&p2=myResizable&p3=&p4=new%2Fisolated%20scope&p5=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22preview-text%22%20ng-if%3D%22showText%22%20my-draggable%3D%22%22%20my-resizable%3D%22%22%20options%3D%22$parent.configs.text%22%3E)

So how can I use the same myOptions in both directives.

```
var App = angular.module('App');

App.controller('myController', ["$scope", function($scope) {
    //..
}]);

App.directive('myDraggable', ['$document', function($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            options: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            //some code here
        }    
    };
}]);

App.directive('myResizable', ['$document', function($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            options: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            //some code here
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using isolated scope you have to use shared scope logic (parent scope).
Just remove 
    scope: { options: '=' } 
or just set scope: false.
And add 
    $scope.options = {} 
in your parent controller.
There is also good [article](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/) about directive scope.

Answer (score 2):

You should see [doc for scopes in directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

> - **no scope** + **no scope** => Two directives which don't require their own scope will use their parent's scope
> - **child scope** + **no scope** => Both directives will share one single child scope
> - **child scope** + **child scope** => Both directives will share one single child scope
> - **isolated scope** + **no scope** => The isolated directive will use it's own created isolated scope. The other directive will use its parent's scope
> - **isolated scope** + **child scope** => **Won't work!** Only one scope can be related to one element. Therefore these directives cannot be applied to the same element.
> - **isolated scope** + **isolated scope** => **Won't work!** Only one scope can be related to one element. Therefore these directives cannot be applied to the same element.

So you have two isolated scope on one element. Just select what scopes you reaaly need possibly child enough.